# Doubt regarding Force-Overlaid Inversion in geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

In this https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c618937h1817004
lemma ,I did not understand what this lemma want to say,i mean,
I understand the inversion part but after that i did not get why it this transformation swaps $B$ and $C$ ,

can anybody please **explain what is meaning of swapping here and how this transformation swaps $B$ and $C$** ?

thankyou very much

Comment: Some minutes after you, this question was asked https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3801558 with a figure displaying a similar issue... to which I gave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $AC^*=AB$. Now join $C^*$ and $B$ and note that $C^*AB$ is isosceles triangle and thus, reflecting about the angle bisector takes $C^*$ to $B$.

Comment: yeah,i get that but how they swaps each other,or swap meaning is this only which yu are mentioning ?

Comment: @Ishan inversion ofc does not swap them! From getting swapped, they mean that point $C$ maps to $B$ by first applying inversion and then reflecting the inverted image about angle bisector.